# How to make Class.getMethod() throw a SecurityException

Tags: java, reflection, junit

I have a utility method to find an object's getter method for a particular field (using reflection):

```
public static Method findGetter(final Object object, final String fieldName) {
    if( object == null ) {
        throw new NullPointerException("object should not be null");
    } else if( fieldName == null ) {
        throw new NullPointerException("fieldName should not be null");
    }

    String getterName = getMethodNameForField(GET_PREFIX, fieldName);

    Class<?> clazz = object.getClass();
    try {
        return clazz.getMethod(getterName);
    } catch(final NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // exception handling omitted
    } catch(final SecurityException e) {
        // exception handling omitted
    }
}
```

I would like to write a unit test that covers the [SecurityException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityException.html) scenario, but how can I make [getMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) throw a SecurityException?

The javadoc states that `getMethod` will throw SecurityException

> If a security manager, s, is present and any of the following
>   conditions is met:
>
> - invocation of s.checkMemberAccess(this, Member.PUBLIC) denies access to the method
> - the caller's class loader is not the same as or an ancestor of the class loader for the current class and invocation of
>     s.checkPackageAccess() denies access to the package of this class

I would prefer to trigger the exception normally, rather than resorting to a mocking framework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager(){
    @Override
    public void checkMemberAccess(Class<?> clazz, int which) {
        throw new SecurityException("Not allowed")
    }
    @Override
    public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
        // allow resetting the SM
    }
});
ClassTest.class.getMethod("foo");
```

Remember to call `System.setSecurityManager(null)` in a `finally` block to restore the original state.

Comment: Thanks @Bozho! It's a highly unlikely scenario, but it's nice to be able to test is easily.

Answer (score 0):

As far as causing this in a regular setting, there are very little cases where this can happen.

Non-public methods will result in a `NoSuchMethodException`, because `getMethod` specifically looks for public methods only. `getDeclaredMethod` will find the method, but allows private/protected methods to be returned.

The only real way to do this is to, as the javadocs say, have a separate package that is protected by the security manager, which I'm guessing can only be done with unsigned applets or similar permissions. (I have never run into this myself, so I am not entirely sure)

Your best bet is forcing the exception to be thrown for specific methods by overriding the security manager.